# Why does this event pattern not produce octave jumps?

Tags: supercollider

I'm trying to learn how to use event patterns. I typed out the following, expecting a sequence which 'jumps down' an octave each time:

```
p = Pbind(*[
    instrument: \mySynth,
    midinote: Pseq([108, 96, 84, 72, 60, 48, 36, 24, 12], inf),
    dur: 0.2
]);

SynthDef(
    "mySynth",
    {
        |midinote, gate = 1|
        var stereofreq = [midinote, midinote];
        var audio = Pulse.ar(stereofreq, 0.5, mul: 0.8);
        var env = Linen.kr(gate, 0.01, 1, 0.1, doneAction: 2);
        OffsetOut.ar(0, audio * env);
    }
).add;

p.play;
```

I certainly get a descending sequence, but the interval is not an octave. Am I missing some detail of the `midinote` key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you are missing something: the data in the `midinote` key is **magically transformed into Hertz values in the `freq` key** when the pattern is played. So when you write your synthdef, you shouldn't use `midinote`, instead use `freq`.

It might seem like suspicious magic, but think about it this way: you can write a SynthDef once, using `freq`, and thereafter you are free to use `midinote` or `freq` or `degree` in your patterns, and they'll all be converted, without you having to rewrite your SynthDef to use the different-named control.

To understand more about what is going on, this page is very helpful: [Pattern Guide 07: Value Conversions](http://doc.sccode.org/Tutorials/A-Practical-Guide/PG_07_Value_Conversions.html)

Comment: I see you're also asking questions about SuperCollider. Is this the right place to go, or is there a more active forum?

Comment: @David: I like SO for this, but the SuperCollider mailing lists have by far the most activity: http://www.birmingham.ac.uk/facilities/BEAST/research/supercollider/mailinglist.aspx (on that page you can sign up to **sc-users**, or view the archives online etc)